# Equation with matrix

Tags: matrices, diophantine-equations

$$
       \begin{pmatrix}
        3 & -1\\
        -4 & 2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}=(X^T+3I)^{-1}
$$

$T$ is the transpose and $-1$ is the inverse and $I$ is the unity matrix.

I have come this far $$
       \begin{pmatrix}
        3 & -1\\
        -4 & 2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}-(3I)^{-1}=(X^T)^{-1}
$$
but how do I remove the $T$ and $-1$?
Made a new solution
$$\left(\begin{matrix}3&-1\\-4&2\\\end{matrix}\right)=X^T+3I$$
$$\left(\begin{matrix}2&1\\4&3\\\end{matrix}\right)-3I=X^T$$
$$\left(\begin{matrix}2&1\\4&3\\\end{matrix}\right)-\left(\begin{matrix}3&0\\0&3\end{matrix}\right)=X^T$$
$$\left(\begin{matrix}-1&1\\4&0\\\end{matrix}\right)=X^T$$
$$X=\left(\begin{matrix}-1&4\\1&0\\\end{matrix}\right)$$
what is wrong with this one?

Comment: You have to invert both sides first.

Comment: Also, $(X^T)^T = X$

Comment: Also note, that you have propably used $(X^T+3I)^{-1} = (X^T)^{-1} + 3I^{-1}$ which is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Lets call the left hand side $A$. You want to solve $A=(X^T+3I)^{-1}$ for $X$. Thus taking the inverse we get $A^{-1} =X^T+3I \Leftrightarrow A^{-1}-3I = X^T \Leftrightarrow X = (A^{-1}-3I)^T$

Comment: Do the $$(A^-1-3I)^T$$ mean that I should transpose both A^-1 and 3I?

Comment: Yes exactly, $(A^{-1}-3I)^T = (A^{-1})^T-3I^T$ and $I^T = I$.

Answer (score 2):

Watch out, there's a bad mistake, it is not true in general that $(a + b)^{-1} = a^{-1} + b^{-1}$.

Instead, invert both sides as it have been suggested by **Matt**, to get
$$
X^{T} + 3 I = \begin{bmatrix}3&-1\\-4&2\end{bmatrix}^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}1&{1}/{2}\\2&{3}/{2}\end{bmatrix}^{-1},
$$
and from there it should be easy.

Comment: I came up with the answer $$\left(\begin{matrix}-1&4\\1&0\\\end{matrix}\right)$$ but it is wrong